# Passing a parameter back to a function with $eval

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to make use of the angular bootstrap components, in particular the tab component. My custom directive currently looks like this:

```
        scope: {
            select: '&select'
          },
        template:   '<tabset>' +
                        '<tab ng-repeat="tab in menu.tabs" disabled="tab.disabled" active="tab.active" select="tabSelected($index)">' +
                            '<tab-heading>' +
                                '<i class={{tab.headingClass}}></i> {{tab.title}}' +
                            '</tab-heading>' +
                            '<div ng-include="tab.partial"></div>' +
                        '</tab>' +
                    '</tabset>',

        controller: 'TabBarController',
```

In the above I can retrieve the current tabs index using the `$index`service and this works fine. In the tabs controller I can access this through the function:

```
$scope.tabSelected = function (tabIndex) { .. };
```

My html (removal.html) uses the directive and its `select` attribute to pass in a function from its own controller (removal-controller.js) for the function above to make use of:

```
 $scope.tabSelected = function (tabIndex) {
    if ($scope.select){
        $scope.$eval( $scope.select({index : tabIndex}) );
    }
};
```

So if **select** receives a function it checks it and is suppose to pass back the tab index - the problem is that I always get back **undefined**. Below is the html where I'm making the link and the removal-controller that needs the tab-index:

```
<div tab-bar file-url="..."
        select="removalModel.onSelected()"
></div>

$scope.removalModel.onSelected = function(tabIndex){
   cvsBoxService.resetScrollToTop('planoRemovalContainer');
   // Always gets back undefined
   console.log( "Tab index:"+tabIndex );
};
```

I hope this was clear....anyway how do you package up a parameter, send it via $eval and make use of it on the other side?

Thanks

Note: I've also tried:

```
$scope.$eval($scope.select(), {index : tabIndex});
```

Comment: It's all a bit confusing, but what I see at once is that you use `$index` in your HTML, whereas you use `index` when you call `select` in your code.

Comment: i know its difficult to explain properly - yeh im creating a JSON object to hold the value of the index

Answer (score 0):

`select` calls `removalModel.onSelected()`. You don't pass any argument to `onSelected`, so `tabIndex` will always be `undefined`.

You need something like `removalModel.onSelected(index)`.

I don't know why you use `$scope.$eval`.